# What is polynomial-time random language?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, computational-complexity, formal-languages, algorithmic-randomness

What is polynomial-time random language?
I have tried to found the definition by searching artilce, but failed. Any one give reference?

Comment: A random language, conditioned on it being in P? Which article are you referring to?

Comment: @ClementC. I am not sure, I have not found any definition of it, it is relating to some theorems. It is relating to my question posted several year ago,.https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157880/every-infinite-c-e-language-is-infinite-or-finite-union-of-regular-languages-inc

Comment: "Which article are you referring to?" Which "theorems," from where?

Comment: and I am embarrassed to ask the solver again about the question

Comment: @ClementC. I have made a mistake. sorry, corrected.

Comment: @TStancek I think possibly it is not the definition. Randomized Polynomial time language = polynomial-time random language

Comment: I think polynomial-time random language is base on resource-bounded complexity, It was initiated by Levin. Here is an article http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397598001194

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [a lecture notes](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/CTFM/CTFM2014/submissions/Kawamura.pdf) to explain p-time random, in one word, an infinite sequence $Z\in \{0,1\}^N$is  resource-bounded/computable random if there  is no computable/resource-bounded martingale that succeeds on $Z$.

So p-time randomness is an infinite sequence $Z\in \{0,1\}^N$ is  p-time random if there  is no p-time computable martingale that succeeds on $Z$.

I think I can say settled now.